# JProfiler Assertion failed

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to launch JProfiler 6 in remote mode and get the following error:

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 28
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
Assertion failed: (agentClassLocal), function initReferences, file /Users/hannes/buildsys/jprofiler/build/src/c/agent/shared/LiveProfilingSession.cpp, line 95.
```

Can someone please explain what they are from and how to fix them?

Thanks!

Comment: I get a very similar error when installing JProfiler 6.2.2 or 6.2.3 on a Linux x64 box with 64-bit Sun Hotspot JVM: java: /home/hannes/buildsys/jprofiler/build/src/c/agent/shared/LiveProfilingSession.cpp:102: void LiveProfiling::initReferences(JNIEnv*): Assertion `controllerClassLocal' failed. - did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the reference to agent.jar:

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/jprofiler/bin/agent.jar
```